# Google Forms to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Can someone help with this?

In a Google Form I have a question in the form of a checkboxes choose where multiple answers can be selected.

In sheets it putting them all into 1 cell, is there a way to make it popular different rows from the 1 question and also duplicate the other information in the form. My like a multi-line cells into new rows, or as a script editor way?

Any help would be really grateful on this issue.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1):

What does the cell with all the responses look like? Is it separating them by commas? Like if in your survey I selected:

- Apples
- Banana
- Orange
- Grapes

then it would put `Apples, Banana, Orange, Grapes` into the cell in google sheets?

If this is the case, as it was when I conducted a survey a while ago, then you could simply use `=SPLIT(A1,",")` (where A1 is the cell with all the responses checked). This will separate the responses into different cells horiziontally. If you would like it to be vertical, use `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,","))`.

Comment: I think this will solve the problem for separating the items, however not sure what is meant by "and also duplicate the other information in the form".

Comment: SO this if the sheet in question. when it up and running it should be all automated as it have 200 surveys done a day as no admin time to manuel do the split and so on. the first 3 row are how it currently doing the output with the example below showing how we want the data to look. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f_iRFKetMztgZ_VFXpTVSfFyrSVRtVXTKViEkh8RFz8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Am I correct in that Column H, Work Areas, is the only one with the check boxes?

Comment: yes you are correct